# jQuery: Check if jQuery object contains (includes) exact DOM element

Tags: jquery, element, contains, exists, selected

I have a reference to a DOM element, and a jQuery object which is the result of a selector, and I want to check if that specific DOM element is in that jQuery object. Short of looping through the whole jQuery object and checking for equality, is there a straightforward way in jQuery to do this?

I have tried `.contains`, `:contains`, `.has` and `:has`, and none of them seem to do the job. Also, I should mention that all the elements I'm working with are on the same DOM tree level, so there is no need to worry about parents/children.

Comment: You need to be clearer on what you are looking for. Are you matching on ID?

Comment: Yeah I should have elaborated more.
1. I do NOT have IDs associated with these elements. It would be alot easier if I did.
2. My actual problem was determining whether an element existed in the previous siblings or next siblings of a given pivot element. Thus, all solutions which require the parent element such as those which use .find() are not applicable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

similar to Gumbos answer, but slimmer:

```
if ( obj.filter(function() { return this == el; }).length ) {
    // obj contains el
}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
$yourJqueryObject.is(yourDomElement)
```

See [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/#is-elements) added in 1.6.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var result = $("selector").find("*").filter(function() {
    return this === elem;
}).length === 1;
```

`elem` is the DOM element you are looking for.

Comment: what I was looking for. The accepted answer was missing the important find("*") part.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to David's answer but even slimmer:

```
if ( obj.filter(el).length ) {
    // obj contains el
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda hackish, but works for me:

```
$.inArray($('#single-element').get(0), $('.many-elements').get()) != -1
```